# Chrome Web Inspector Not Making Live Changes?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

So I'm running my Rails app on a Nitrous.io server, and Chrome's web inspector is displaying some weird behavior that I've never seen before. When I try and modify some CSS in the web inspector, it automatically switches back to the previous CSS and doesn't make any live changes. I've never experienced this before and rely heavily on web inspector to work on the CSS of my site.

I'm currently running Chrome OS v29.0.1547.74 on a stable build.

I would post my css file but it's pretty long. Any idea where I should start looking to debug this? I really need to be able to make live changes in the browser to work on this site.

My CSS passes the W3C CSS Validator, all I get are warnings for 'unknown vendor prefixes'.

Comment: Any JavaScript running on your page? If so, have you tried removing it to see if the CSS problem continues to occur?